# Validating a textbox

Tags: php, html, mysql, textbox

I am having a table inside a form. I want all the three columns details to be entered by the user. if the user leaves anyone of them, it should show an alert message like "Please enter the name, it cannot be blank". if all the fields are filled then only the insert into should come into act.

```
<table> <!--cellpadding=15 cellspacing=3-->
    <tr><td>Name</td><td>: <input type="text" name="name"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Address</td><td>: <input type="text" name="address"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Phone No</td><td>: <input type="text" name="dept_id"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: take a look at `jquery` `validate` very easy to use for your requirment

Comment: i don't want to use javascript. can it be done in php.

Comment: And What have you tried?

Comment: browser interactions like alert boxes needs to be programmed from a client side language.

Comment: There are two sides of user input validation. Which do you prefer? client side (Javascript) or server side (PHP, ASP, Ruby, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a flag variable.

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="nameId">
<input type="text" name="address" id="addressId">
<input type="text" name="dept_id" id="dept_id">
```

Call this method in `onSubmit()`

```
function validate()
{
  var validate = false;
  if(document.getElementById("nameId").value == "")
  {  
      alert("NAME IS REQUIRED");
     validate   = true;
  }
  ...................    

  ...................   


return validate ;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = trim($_POST['name']);
if (empty($name))
    echo 'name is empty';
```

do this for rest of the fields

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="get" enctype="text/plain"action="">
<table> <!--cellpadding=15 cellspacing=3-->

<? if($_GET['name'] == "") print "Please enter the name, it cannot be blank"; ?>
<tr><td>Name</td><td>: <input type="text" name="name"></td></tr>

<? if($_GET['address'] == "") print "Please enter the Address, it cannot be blank"; ?>  
<tr><td>Address</td><td>: <input type="text" name="address"></td></tr>

<? if($_GET['dept_id'] == "") print "Please enter the Phone No, it cannot be blank"; ?>    
<tr><td>Phone No</td><td>: <input type="text" name="dept_id"></td></tr>

</table>
</form>
```

and don't forget to properly escape user input!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `javascript` validation on form submit. Look at it below example.

`myForm` is `form name` , `onSubmit` call function `validateForm()`

```
function validateForm()
{
   if (document.myForm.name.value == "")
   {
      alert("Please enter the name");
      document.myForm.name.focus();
      return false;
   }
   if (document.myForm.address.value == "")
   {
      alert("Please enter the address");
      document.myForm.address.focus();
      return false;
   }
   if (document.myForm.dept_id.value == "")
   {
      alert("Please enter the department id");
      document.myForm.dept_id.focus();
      return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your complete code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
   if (document.test.name.value == "")
   {
      alert("Please enter the name");
      document.test.name.focus();
      return false;
   }
   if (document.test.address.value == "")
   {
      alert("Please enter the address");
      document.test.address.focus();
      return false;
   }
   if (document.test.dept_id.value == "")
   {
      alert("Please enter the department id");
      document.test.dept_id.focus();
      return false;
   }
   return true;
}
</script>



<form method="post" name="test" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
   <table> <!--cellpadding=15 cellspacing=3-->
       <tr><td>Name</td><td>: <input type="text" name="name"></td></tr>
       <tr><td>Address</td><td>: <input type="text" name="address"></td></tr>
       <tr><td>Phone No</td><td>: <input type="text" name="dept_id"></td></tr>
      <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit_form" /></td></tr>
   </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {

$("#registration_form").validate({

    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            lettersonly:true
        },
         contact: {
            required: true,
            numbers:true,
            minlength:10,
            maxlength:11
       }
}
 messages: {
        name: {
            required: "<h4><span style='color:red'>Please Enter your Name</span></h4>",
            lettersonly: "<h4><span style='color:red'>Numbers And Symbols Not Allowed</span></h4>"
        },
         contact: {
            required: "<h4><span style='color:red'>Please Enter your Phone number</span></h4>",
            numbers: "<h4><span style='color:red'>Character And Symbols Are Not Allowed</span></h4>",
            minlength: "<h4><span style='color:red'>Your phone Number Must Be At Least 10 Characters Long</span></h4>",
            maxlength: "<h4><span style='color:red'>Please Enter No More Than 11 Numbers</span></h4>"
        }
}
 submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});  }); 

  jQuery.validator.addMethod("numbers", function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || /^[0-9]+$/i.test(value);
}, "numbers only please");
```

the name is the id of Name field and contact is the id of Phone number Field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML for this kind of validation.

```
<input type="text" name="name" required>
```

When the user fails to fill this field , while submitting it will show a pop up message saying *Please fill out this field*.